# Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `db`:`5432`

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to connect to the postgres database (in db container) from another container. My app is using Prisma orm. I'm getting the following error over and over again:

```
=> ERROR [development 7/8] RUN npx prisma db push                                                       9.8s 
------                                                                                                        
 > [development 7/8] RUN npx prisma db push:                                                                  
#0 9.220 Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma                                                       
#0 9.235 Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "prismadb", schema "public" at "db:5432"                        
#0 9.701                                                                                                      
#0 9.704 Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `db`:`5432`
#0 9.704 
#0 9.704 Please make sure your database server is running at `db`:`5432`.
------
```

failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npx prisma db push]: exit code: 1

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: api
    build: 
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      target: development
    command: npm run start:debug
    restart: unless-stopped
    links:
      - "db"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - PORT=${PORT}
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME}
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
      - 9229:9229
    volumes: 
      - ./api:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - webnet
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:15.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Dockerfile for api container

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG DATABASE_HOST=db
ENV DATABASE_URL="postgresql://${DATABASE_USER}:${DATABASE_PASSWORD}@${DATABASE_HOST}:5432/prismadb?schema=public"
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate

RUN npx prisma db push

RUN npm run build

FROM node:14-alpine AS production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

.env file

```
PORT=4000

DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_USER=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
DATABASE_NAME=prismadb
```

Comment: Can you check if you are able to connect to the database running in the container from any Database IDE?

Comment: @NurulSundarani yes.

Comment: @NurulSundarani my assumption is that the database container is not initialized yet, and prisma cannot connect to it. I've tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in prisma db push. This command should be run after the initialization of the containers, through docker exec.